# Incomprehensible syntax in Python - passing variables as arguments

Tags: python, function

I cannot find anywhere why to use and if are there any diffrences between these 2 calls:

```
someFunction(10)
```

and

```
someFunction(x=10)
```

Comment: Not if you have a parameter called `x`.

Comment: So when to use it?

Comment: keyword arguments can be passed in any order, but positional arguments cannot. see args vs kwargs.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial invocation of the function is using a positional argument - that is, it will match the '10' with the first parameter of the argument.

However, if you explicitly call the function with a keyword argument, it will match the value with the specified keyword.

```
def kwarg_func(x = 5, y = 10, z = 2):
    return x * y * z

# will return 200 (10 * 10 * 2)
print(kwarg_func(10))
# will return 10 (5 * 1 * 2)
print(kwarg_func(y = 1))
# will throw an error since keyword 'a' is undefined
print(kwarg_func(a = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

So the reason you'd really be passing x=10, is if it was a [**kwarg](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/) or if x is set in the variable

```
def somefunction(x=5):
    print(x*x)

somefunction(x=10)
```

That would result in 10*10, thus 100.

The reason behind this is that Python accepts *positional* arguments which are effectively:

```
def somefunction(x)
    #dosomestuff
```

Where x in somefunction is in position 0 for the arguments you can pass to it.

Where as:

```
def somefunction(x=10)
    #dosomestuff
```

Is a keyword argument (but you can use its position as well)

A positional argument *must* be before a keyword argument.

The python tutorial has a good touch on this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague and it depends on your function construction.
Suppose, you have a function:

```
def someFunction(x):
    return x
```

Then you can call it via `someFunction(10)` or `someFunction(x=10)` while the latter is more verbose but the first will totally suffice. Look up `args` and `**kwargs` for a better understanding, e.g. [here](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/).

Answer (score 0):

there is a major importance of `args` and `kwargs`. first of all `10` is the `arg`(argument) and `x=10`(keyword argument) is called `kwarg`.

the most basic difference between these two is args are taken in order and kwargs are not.
kwargs can be given in any order.

before reading this answer I hope you have some knowledge on python default arguments.

```
def func(a=25, b, c, d=3, e, f=2, g, h=1, i):
    return a * b * c * d * e * f * g * h * i
```

in this function, you can pass all the arguments or you can pass only essential arguments
essential arguments are `b`, `c`, `e`, `g`, `i`

and default arguments are `a`, `d`, `f`, `h`. 
So the question becomes how to pass values only for essential arguments.

the answer is kwargs. since for kwargs, there is no importance of the order we can pass the arguments as `func(b=3, c=4, e=2, g=10)` or `func(c=4, g=10, b=3, e=2)` any combination would work for this.